# Continuous Resource Allocation / Knapsack Problem

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, optimization, mathematical-optimization, knapsack-problem

I'm trying to create an algorithm to solve the following optimization problem with each x_i and B as integers and all f_i's are monotonic, non-linear functions. This looks like a knapsack or continuous resource allocation problem to me. EDIT: The constant C is an integer
[image: Optimization Problem]

I initially tried solving it by comparing the marginal cost for all of the g_i(x), this did not work since the Cs cancel. The comparison I was doing was looking for the i that would minimize g_i(x) - g_i(x - j), where j is a small value. In this case:

g_i(x) - g_i(x - j) = f_i(x) + c - (g_i(x - j) + c), so the cs would cancel out.

Does anyone know of a solution for this, or have any clue on how to attempt this? I'd appreciate if anyone had any literature on this topic.

Thank you.

Comment: The +C makes this more of a discrete problem. You could brute force the set of i such that x_i > 0, or if you specify the functions in greater detail, an exact or approximate integer program formulation might be possible.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat The equations are non-linear monotonic (and estimating them as linear would cause too much of an error, linear programming will not work). The constant C is also an integer.

Have you seen similar problems like this (including the + C term) before? If so, could you point me to places where they may list out a solution?

Comment: Piecewise linear? Convex? Monotone is a very weak assumption.

Comment: It's a little bit like a degenerate capacitated facility location problem with splittable demands.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Thank you for the fast reply. Let's assume the equations are convex

Comment: Fixed-charge problems are well-studied for the linear case. Not so much for non-linear problems. I would start throwing this at an MINLP solver.

Answer (score 1):

So we have some facilities that can be open with some cost C or closed with cost 0, and the marginal cost for an open facility to serve each additional unit never goes down (`f_i` is convex).

If we knew which facilities were open, then we'd know we have an optimal assignment when all of the marginal costs for the next unit at each facility are greater than or equal to all of the marginal costs of the last unit at each facility (as you observed). If the functions have some special form, there's probably a better way to do this, but in general we can use binary search to find the minimum marginal cost that lets us serve the demand (where each iteration also uses binary search to determine how much each open facility can serve).

If instead we only knew that exactly k facilities should be open, we can still do binary search for the minimum marginal cost. We just have to figure out how many units each facility can serve without exceeding the proposed marginal cost, and then select the top k.

Finally, observe that we can just try all k from 0 to n and take the best solution we find.